# generate update query using django orm

Tags: python, django, orm, sql-update

I need to implement this query using django orm:

```
update table set field=field+1 where id=id
```

I don't whant to use this:

```
o = model.objects.get(id=id)
o.field+=1
o.save()
```

because it use select and when update, and not thread safe.

How to implement this via orm?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both the previous answerers have part of the solution: you should use `update` in conjunction with `F()`:

```
Model.objects.filter(id=id).update(field=F('field') +1))
```

Note this does an in-place UPDATE without any need for SELECT at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update`, details can be found in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update)

Comment: OP wants to update attributes based on existing fields in a thread safe way, which is done by F() Expressions. I don't think update has such functionality. are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

for `django` v 2.2 (and maybe 3+) SQL statement compilation function could be:

```
from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import UpdateQuery

def compile_update_query(query_set, update_kwargs):
    query = query_set.query.chain(UpdateQuery)
    query.add_update_values(update_kwargs)
    return str(query)
```

where `query_set` is `MyShinyModel.objects.filter(id=42)` and `update_kwargs` is a dictionary of model fields to update

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **convert** the `UPDATE ORM` query to `UPDATE SQL` statement without performing it

> The update() method is applied instantly and returns the number of rows matched by the query  ([django 1.8 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once))

```
def generate_update_sql(queryset, update_kwargs):
    """  [checked on django 1.8]
    Converts queryset with update_kwargs
    like if was: queryset.update(**update_kwargs)
    """
    from django.db.models import sql

    query = queryset.query.clone(sql.UpdateQuery)
    query.add_update_values(update_kwargs)
    compiler = query.get_compiler(queryset.db)
    sql, params = compiler.as_sql()
    return sql % params
```

**Usage**

```
qs = Event.objects.exclude(app='some')
update_kwargs = dict(description='test', action='action')
generate_update_sql(qs, update_kwargs)
```

**Will return**

```
UPDATE `api_event` SET `description` = test, `action` = action WHERE NOT (`api_event`.`app` = some)
```