# Django bulk update with string replace

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am trying to update and modify a string field Django's ORM.  The equivalent SQL to do this is:

```
UPDATE example_table SET string_field = REPLACE(string_field, 'old text', 'new text');
```

With that query, I expect `old text` and `old text more text` to be replaced with `new text` and `new text more text` respectively, for all the entries in the `string_field` column.

[Bulk update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) seems promising, but doesn't allow me to modify only part of the field, and [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) only implement numeric changes, not string replace.  I also looked at using [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) to run the above SQL, but that seems like a sideways hack (especially since F() exists to do the same functionality on numbers), and I couldn't get them to actually execute.

I ended up with this, but it seems a shame to execute all the extra queries when I know there's a one line SQL statement to do it.

```
for entry in ExampleModel.objects.all():
    entry.string_field = entry.string_field.replace('old text', 'new text', 1)
    entry.save()
```

Does this feature not exist in Django's ORM for strings yet? Is there something I overlooked in the docs?

Related SO questions:

- [generate update query using django orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319875/generate-update-query-using-django-orm)
- [SQL statement to remove part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030143/sql-statement-to-remove-part-of-a-string)

Comment: I have come with this problem back there. The best way I could found is to do the string processing in Python code. If you do not mind using raw SQL, the replace function is quite consistent between any databases.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Tested with django 1.9

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

ExampleModel.objects.filter(<condition>).update(
    string_field=Func(
        F('string_field'),
        Value('old text'), Value('new text'),
        function='replace',
    )
)
```

**UPDATE Django 2.1**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#replace

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Replace

ExampleModel.objects.filter(<condition>).update(
    string_field=Replace('string_field', Value('old text'), Value('new text'))
)
```

Comment: Works on **`1.8+`** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions and PostgreSQL

Comment: Working on 1.11 with mysql (mariadb)

Comment: wokring on 10.6.7-MariaDB

Answer (score 5):

You could make your own `F`-like object to represent the string replacing in SQL. Here is a proof of concept:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import ExpressionNode

class StringReplaceF(ExpressionNode):
    def __init__(self, field, replace_from, replace_to):
        self.field = field
        self.replace_from = replace_from
        self.replace_to = replace_to
        super(StringReplaceF, self).__init__()

    def evaluate(self, evaluator, qn, connection):
        return (
            "REPLACE({}, %s, %s)".format(self.field),
            (self.replace_from, self.replace_to)
        )

 >>> f = StringReplaceF('string_field', 'old text', 'new text')
 >>> ExampleModel.objects.update(string_field=f)
```

You'd need to do a bit more work with the class if you need it to behave nicely with other `F` objects, but then again, the existing `F` objects don't seem to work with strings anyway.

Comment: Any idea what the Django version and DBMS support for this is?

Comment: Not sure exactly. I just tried it on 1.6.6; I expect it would work in (much) earlier versions but not sure of the specifics. SQL-wise, the `REPLACE` function seems to exist in that form in at least Postgres, MySQL and SQLite.

Answer (score 3):

**New in Django 2.1** - [Replace database function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#replace)

Your example can now be expressed most easily via:

```py
ExampleModel.objects.update(
    string_field=Replace('string_field', Value('old_text'), Value('new_text'))
)
```

Comment: You have extra `)` after `Replace`

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace_field_substring(YourModel, "your_field", "value_from", "value_to")`

```
from django.db.models import F, Value, QuerySet
from django.db.models.functions import Replace

def replace_field_substring(model_or_qs, field, value_from, value_to):
    """Generates ORM partial replace, which can be used in Django ORM data migrations,
    for example for partial replace tbl.cont from="twitter.com" to="x.com" will give you
    UPDATE tbl SET cont = REPLACE(cont, 'twitter.com', 'x.com') WHERE cont LIKE '%twitter.com%';
    """
    qs = model_or_qs if isinstance(model_or_qs, QuerySet) else model_or_qs.objects.all()
    replacement_expression = Replace(F(field), Value(value_from), Value(value_to))
    qs.update(**{field: replacement_expression})
```

Answer (score -1):

Django 2.2 support bulk update, can you using function that one.

Check this one : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create