# Django: how to add a custom attribute to each element of queryset without N+1 request?

Tags: sql, django

Suppose that I have a very basic user model with name and age:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = CharField()  # e.g. John Smith
    age = IntegerField()  # e.g. 21
```

I want to filter users 18+ y/o and for each of them add a special attribute `namesakes` (for instance, for `"John Smith"` it would be something like `["John Williams", "John for Neumann", ...]`).

I know, how to do this in N+1 requests:

```
for user in User.objects.filter(age__gt=18):
    user.namesakes = User.objects.filter(name__startswith=user.name.split()).\
                                   all()
```

But how do I do this in one-ish request? Ideally, for each `User` object in queryset I'd like to create a custom attribute `namesakes` that contained a queryset of namesakes. This is very similar to what [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) or [prefetch_related() with to_attr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) do, but not exactly.

I'd also prefer to avoid using raw SQL, if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: The closest I could see was [this answer about doing your own F expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821724/1081569). If you could combine that with an SQL function to split strings, like [Postgres `substring(string from pattern)` or `split_part`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html), maybe you could do it. It may be database specific, which you seem to want to avoid (no raw SQL), but I haven't seen a function in Django to split strings.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Thank you, Paulo, I think that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [blog post](http://www.merixstudio.com/blog/neat-features-django-orm/), doing something very similar to what I need and.... dear god...

```
>>> from django.db.models import F, Q, Case, IntegerField, Sum, Value, When
>>> from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
>>> pizzas = Pizza.objects.annotate(
...     uses_name_of_another_pizza_as_name_prefix=Coalesce(
...         Sum(
...             Case(
...                 When(
...                     Q(
...                         ~Q(pk=F('category__pizzas')) &
...                         Q(name__startswith=F('category__pizzas__name'))
...                     ),
...                     then=Value(1)
...                 ),
...                 output_field=IntegerField(),
...             ),
...         ),
...         0,
...     ),
... )
>>> [p, p.uses_name_of_another_pizza_as_name_prefix for p in pizzas]
[
    (<Pizza: Hawaiian>, 0),
    (<Pizza: Hawaiian King>, 1),
    (<Pizza: Pepperoni>, 0),
]
```

Still, it doesn't allow for what I need precisely. So, I preferred to go with raw SQL.

Comment: Nice! I had seen some things with `Concat`, but not `Coalesce`. That said, if I understand correctly, for your use case you would need a 'John' in the DB (with no surname) to look for namesakes of John, right?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Yep, this post doesn't solve my problem entirely - it counts namesakes, but doesn't return the list of them. `Coalesce` doesn't really play a big role here - it just provides a 0 default, I believe. I still haven't found a good way to do my self-join, unfortunately :)